# How to split a string without losing any word?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am using Eclipse for Java and I want to split an input line without losing any characters.

For example, the input line is:

```
IPOD6 1 USD6IPHONE6 16G,64G,128G USD9,USD99,USD999MACAIR 2013-2014 USD123MACPRO 2013-2014,2014-2015 USD899,USD999
```

and the desired output is:

```
IPOD6 1 USD6
IPHONE6 16G,64G,128G USD9,USD99,USD999
MACAIR 2013-2014 USD123
MACPRO 2013-2014,2014-2015 USD899,USD999
```

I was using `split("(?<=\\bUSD\\d{1,99}+)")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you instead use a Scanner? I feel like it would be much easier to tokenize using that approach.

Comment: Do you want to split the input into arrays or just add newlines if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a non-word boundary `\B` inside the positive look-behind. `\B` matches between two non-word characters or between two word characters. It won't split on the boundary which exists between `USD9` and comma in this `USD9,` substring because there is a word boundary exits between `USD9` and comma since 9 is a word character and `,` is a non-word character. It splits on the boundary which exists between `USD6` and `IPHONE6` because there is a non-word boundary `\B` exists between those substrings since `6` is a word character and `I` is also a word character.

```
String s = "IPOD6 1 USD6IPHONE6 16G,64G,128G USD9,USD99,USD999MACAIR 2013-2014 USD123MACPRO 2013-2014,2014-2015 USD899,USD999";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\bUSD\\d{1,99}+\\B)");
for(String i: parts)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
IPOD6 1 USD6
IPHONE6 16G,64G,128G USD9,USD99,USD999
MACAIR 2013-2014 USD123
MACPRO 2013-2014,2014-2015 USD899,USD999
```

Answer (score 1):

without making it too complicated, use this pattern

```
(?=IPOD|IPHONE|MAC)
```

and replace with new line
now it is easy to capture or split into an array
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/245)

---

or maybe this pattern

```
((USD\d+,?)+)
```

and replace w/ `$1\n`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/246)